# Angular 6 path params issues

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Below is the issue which I am encountering when  I use children route to move to edit-todo page driven by Todo component, using angular 6.

When I nest the path as children like below, I am not able to get value of  :id

```
{ path: 'edit-todo', component: EditTodoComponent, children:[
{path: ':id', component: EditTodoComponent}
 ]},

 console.log(activatedRoute.snapshot.url);
```

When separate the route I am able to get the value of id.

```
{ path: 'edit-todo', component: EditTodoComponent},
{ path: 'edit-todo/:id', component: EditTodoComponent },

 console.log(activatedRoute.snapshot.url);
```

Is it possible to get the value of ID using the children[] array shown in approach 1.

Comment: The first approach doesn't make much sense. Why would you display an EditTodo component inside another EditTodo component?

Comment: have you added the module that has ``editTodoComponent`` in the ``app-routing.module.ts`` ?  Also i agree with @JBNizet here .